# How can i export eclipse rcp product without packaging dependencies into plugins folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I need to export an eclipse RCP Application. While exporting, all the plugins that are added as dependencies are packaged into the product/plugins directory as show in the image. Is it possible to export the eclipse product without packaging some huge plugins and refer it from other location?

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the plugins from the plugins directory and adapt the config file using the environment variable like below to refer the bundles from the user defined location

This is supported in org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_V1.3.0 or higher. You can use the environment variables like

**osgi.bundles=$variable_name$/bundle-name.jar**.

While parsing the config file, The launcher will substitute the value of the variable and start the bundle from the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

The folder contains the plugins/fragments you added to your Target Platform and are also referenced as a Dependecy in your Features/Product.

To reduce it's size, remove unnecessary plugins from your target platform (ie. remove all and add required only) and use the 'Find unused dependencies' wizard at your plug-ins. I would start with the latter.

If it's still not enough then additionally you could modify the OSGi class-loader. See this QA:
[Loading of OSGi bundle dynamically from a file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15427069/3589971)

Comment: ya some of my required plugins are of huge size. so i need to have my required plugins in some other directory and refer it while launching the product.

Comment: That's pretty much how the RCP platform works. But it's open source, so you know... :)

Comment: is there any shortcuts  available to achieve this without spending huge effort ?

Comment: I've added a new section to the answer, it looks like a shortcut

Comment: Do you have any idea which class reads the config.ini file while starting the rcp application? so that i can modify the file to read the environment variables